# Replacing missing values gives no error but doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I used this method to fill in the missing values in a certain range of a column. It gives me no error but does not actually replace the missing values.
Something might be wrong with the logic of the code.
I had the same number of NaNs before replacing.

[image: code]:

```py
Lan = data["Group"].loc[57:70]
Lan.replace(np.nan, "Lan", inplace=True)
Act = data["Group"].loc[89:102]
Act.replace(np.nan, "Act", inplace=True)
data["Group"].isna().sum() # 28
```

Comment: Please, could you put the code into the question directly via markdown? How many NaNs did you have before replacing?

Comment: Would you provide us with a **minimal reproducible example** and possibly a sample dataset?

Comment: You need use `fillna`, ie, `df.loc[0:3, 'Group'] = df['Group'].fillna('Lan')`

Comment: You're trying to replace a floating point number, NaN, with a string; if the column type is string as well, there won't be any NaNs in the column, so nothing can be replaced. Try replacing `None` instead; but `fillna` is better.